# JPA with composite key and secondary table

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to JPA an I have a problem when trying to work with a secondary table and a composite key.

I get the following error message when I try to add, delete or update:

> Provided id of the wrong type Expected: class EmployeePK, got class
>   java.lang.Integer

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeePK.class)
@Table(name="specialemployee")
@SecondaryTable(name = "employeeTypeAndSalary", pkJoinColumns = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_Id"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_Email") })
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public enum EmployeeType {
        WORKER, FOREMAN, MANAGEMENT
    }

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMP")
    @Embedded
    private Name name;

    @Id
    private String email;

    private Date birthDate;

    @Lob
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "EMP_SALARY", table = "employeeTypeAndSalary")
    private double salary;

    @Column(name = "EMP_TYPE", table = "employeeTypeAndSalary")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmployeeType employeeType;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(int id, Name name, String email, double salary, String birthDate,
            String comments, EmployeeType employeeType) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.salary = salary;
        try {
            this.birthDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(birthDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            logging.error("error on creating date" + " :" + e);
            this.birthDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf("1900-00-00");
        }

        this.comments = comments;
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
    }

    //getters and setters
}


public class EmployeePK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String email;

    // non-arg default constructor

    public EmployeePK() {
        super();
    }

    public EmployeePK(int id, String email){
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    protected void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        return ((o instanceof EmployeePK) && 
            email.equals(((EmployeePK)o).getEmail()) &&
            id == ((EmployeePK) o).getId());
    }

    public int hashCode() { 
        return (int) (email.hashCode() + id); 
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class Name implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I have been looking at it for some time now and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks.

Edited :

```
Name name1 = new Name("Johnn", "Doe");


Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, name1, "employee1@hotmail.com",
            1857.87, "1976-05-12", "ready for promotion",
            EmployeeType.MANAGEMENT);


addEmployee(employee1);


private static void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_excercise");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logging.error("This error has occured when adding a employee"
                + " :" + e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you try and create an employee? Given the code in your question you defined two identifiers on the Employee class (`id` and `email`), neither of which is `EmployeePK`.

Comment: Include full exception and stack

Comment: :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class Employee. Expected: class EmployeePK, got class java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found.  Add method didn't had any problems.  Issue in update method where I forgot to change the logging text so it seemed that the problem whas in teh add method.  Issue solved